# Dynamically adding a class to a specific row in a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called "anotherWay" which listens to some event and then tries to dynamically add a class to a table row.

This can be seen in the file customTable.js in this plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/He11jnAYbDVShJEzHis8

However when i use the statement, it fails to attach the class.

```
element[0].rows[index].addClass('highlight');
```

any clues how this can be resolved ?

Comment: When is `scope.$on('downMovement')` fired?

Comment: when you hit g and then 1 on the keyboard

Comment: Ah I see, from app.js. I've updated my Plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addClass` is a jqLite function, not a function on a DOM element.

**Solution 1 - Vanilla JS:**

```
var row = element[0].rows[index];

if (row.classList) row.classList.add('highlight');
else row.className += ' ' + 'highlight';
```

**Solution 2 - jqLite:**

```
var row = element[0].rows[index];

angular.element(row).addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: Though these look like they'd work, neither of these are the "Angular way" which would imply using something like ng-class.

Comment: While ng-class is the Angular way, it will add multiple unnecessary watchers. I'm also explaining why his attempt is failing.

Comment: Good point, but it's likely that the highlighted row will eventually change at some point. I believe also in the docs it mentions Angular can handle ~1000 or so watchers before becoming a performance issue, which is probably too much data for humans to handle on a single view.

Comment: Fair enough; savings like this 1000 times on a page would be prime.

Answer (score 2):

Try using ng-class:

```
<tr ng-class="{'highlighted': highlightedRows[$index] == true}" ng-repeat="element in body">
```

And then in your directive:

```
angular.module('CustomTable').directive('anotherWay',[function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope,element,attrs,controller){
      scope.highlightedRows = {};
      scope.$on('downMovement',function(event,index){
        index = parseInt(index);
        console.log("Row that should be highlighted is :" + index);
        scope.highlightedRows[index] = true;

      });

    } //end link

  }; // end return

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of traversing through the  elements on a click, update `scope.rowSelected` whenever you'd like, and add an `ng-class` attribute to the `<tr />` elements.

Example:

`<tr ng-repeat="element in body" ng-class="{ highlight: rowSelected == $index }">`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JsiqMJftYQ1gDJgTdyTr?p=preview)